Medieval movie with battles on snowy landscapes and a man who falls in love then drinks poison
I watched this movie about 12 years ago (~2004). I can remember the following facts:

It was set in medieval time
The movie starts with battle on snowy and icy landscape, bows, swords, etc
The main character falls in love with a girl
The main character drinks a poison to forget about the girl
At the end of the movie he dies and gets sent in the sea on a boat to burn
The girl jumps in, takes his sword and kills herself too.


I think you might mean Tristan & Isolde. I can't be sure, because it's a 2006 movie and you mentioned having seen it 12 years ago. But I remember the dying in a boat ending very clearly from this movie.



